# CuserPoints not working

Tags: jomsocial

I found this snippet of code and I've managed to include this in my "handle posts" code so I expect to see points added to my profile each time a "add a trail".

```
    include_once JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
    include_once JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_community/libraries/userpoints.php';
    CuserPoints::assignPoint('trail.add');
```

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: I included this code and it does not throw any exceptions, however I am not seeing points get added to my profile. The points system works inside of JomSocial when I upload an image to the community, but not when I try to add points externally using this code.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found this PDF:
https://www.joomlapolis.com/media/kunena/attachments/557850/developer_documentation_2.0.x_english.pdf

I found that using AlphaUserPointsHelper was the way to go.

```
// get AlphaUserPointsHelper
$api_AUP = JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_alphauserpoints' . DS .'helper.php';
if (file_exists($api_AUP)) {
   require_once ($api_AUP);
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   $referrerId = AlphaUserPointsHelper::getReferreid($user->id);
   AlphaUserPointsHelper::newPoints('custom.function.name', $referrerId);
}
```